# Why can you not use equation of motion $v^2 - u^2 = 2as$ when attempting escape velocity questions?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, escape-velocity

There is the this question:

Imagine you are projecting a ball with $3/4$th the escape velocity from the surface of the earth. What is the farthest distance will it reach it from the centre of earth? ($R=$ Radius of the earth)

The answer given in my workbook is $16R/7$

I could solve this question using the conservation of energy theorem. Why can I not use the third equation of motion

$$v^2 - u^2 = 2as~?$$

$s=$ distance from the surface of the earth

I tried solving through the equation of motion method but my answer is widely different.

Comment: Escape velocity is the speed at which an object can coast to an arbitrary ("infinite") distance from a massive body (i.e. it leaves and never comes back). If you take the limit of that equation as *s* goes to infinity, you get *v* going to infinity as well - but that contradicts the very idea of an escape velocity, that there is a finite speed which is sufficient to escape a massive body.

Comment: What value did you use for $a$?

Comment: I used -9.8 for a due to the fact that g is a downward force and I utilised the convention using a negative notation.

Answer (score 6):

That equation is for constant acceleration motions. The value of $g$ decreases with altitude according to $g=\frac{GM}{r^2}$. In this problem, the decrease in $g$ is significant, as you could expect the projectile to reach a great height.

Comment: So, am I not supposed to use the equations of motion in these questions? How do I determine if I can use these equations as I had been previously using these equations in other questions and they worked but in this one they didn't.

Comment: You can use  equations of motion, but they have to be the correct ones.  To see which ones are correct you need to understand their derivations.

Comment: @SnehalSaurabh $v^2-u^2=2as$ Doesn't describe all types of motion. It only describes *one specific type* (constant acceleration). Most motion is not constant acceleration motion, and so this equation doesn't apply most of the time.

Comment: In my opinion it is regrettable that some teachers and textbooks call this set of equations *equations of motion*. The name makes it sound as if the equations were generally applicable. I much prefer *suvat equations* or *constant acceleration equations*.

Comment: Thank you. Helps a lot.